# Cannot unhide a single image

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery, i would like to ask for your support on how to unhide a single image from another div. Because I hide all the `<img>` tagged and I would like to unhide the single image for Description purposes.

Comment: And what does the HTML look like. And your code to hide the images. You could just say something like `$('#yourimageid').show();`

Comment: To help you, please provide your code and what have you tried and/or a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: Was some of these answer useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

give an Id to your image and unhide it

```
<img id="image1" src="...."/>


$('#image1').show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet

```
$("#imageDivId").show();
```

You can also use div class instead of id. For using class

```
 $(".imageDivClass").show();
```

you can also `toggle` between the hide() and show() methods with the toggle() method.

```
 $("#imageDivId").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **ID** you can use `$('#img_ID').show();`

If you use **class** you can use `$('.img_CLASS').show();`

If you use **parent div** with ID to target img you can use `$('#div_ID img').show();`

This is with jQuery [**.show()**](http://api.jquery.com/show/), you can also use jQuery [**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which will show / hide the img depending on if its visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which image needs shown:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
<div id="show"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></div>

$('img').hide();
$('#show img').show();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4BxS/